# Как собрать из заглавных букв одно слово?

Tags: python-3.x

Дана строка. В ней несколько слов. Некоторые слова начинаются с заглавных букв. Нужно создать слово в виде строки из этих заглавных букв.

```
def m (t) :
    if t.istitle() is True :
        return t.istitle()       # вот на этом я застрял
```

Comment: в сторону: не используйте `if t.istitle() is True :   return t.istitle()` или `if t.istitle():        return t.istitle()`. Пишите просто: `def m(t): return t.istitle()` или `m = methodcaller('istitle')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет никаких проблем. Строки в *Python 3* по умолчанию в *Unicode*.

```
s_in = "Мама Мыла Раму"
u = [c for c in s_in if c.isupper()]
s_out = ''.join(u)
print(s_out)
```

Comment: В Питоне 2: `filter(unicode.istitle, u"Мама Мыла Раму")`. Нужно заметить, что это не только заглавные буквы в начале слов собирает.¶ Понятие [`isupper()` может отличаться от `istitle()`](http://unicode.org/faq/casemap_charprop.html#4) в Юникоде: `'\u01c8'.isupper() is False`, но `'\u01c8'.istitle() is True`